# GraphQL useLazyQuery typescript fetchPolicy problem

Tags: typescript, graphql

I'm using GraphQL code generator to create typescript types of my schema entities. When I use useQuery like below there is no problem;

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery<
    FavoritesQuery,
    FavoritesQueryVariables
  >({
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });
```

However, when I try lazy query like below, typescript compiler suffers;

```
const [loadFavorites, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery<
    FavoritesQuery,
    FavoritesQueryVariables
  >(Queries.FAVORITES_QUERY, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });
```

Intellisense finds `fetchPolicy` and its value list while typing. But compiler generates below error;

```
Argument of type '{ fetchPolicy: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LazyQueryHookOptions<{ __typename?: "MainQuery"; } & { favorites: ({ __typename?: "FavoriteGType"; } & Pick<FavoriteGType, "id" | "name" | "category" | "description" | "commandText" | "lastUpdatedDate"> & { ...; })[]; }, FavoritesQueryVariables>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fetchPolicy' does not exist in type 'LazyQueryHookOptions<{ __typename?: "MainQuery"; } & { favorites: ({ __typename?: "FavoriteGType"; } & Pick<FavoriteGType, "id" | "name" | "category" | "description" | "commandText" | "lastUpdatedDate"> & { ...; })[]; }, FavoritesQueryVariables>'.  TS2345

    89 |     FavoritesQueryVariables
    90 |   >(Queries.FAVORITES_QUERY, {
  > 91 |     fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
       |     ^
    92 |   });
```

How should I use fetchPolicy in useLazyQuery?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Apollo 3 uses Typescript's `Omit` functionality, which was added in Typescript 3.5. I have a feeling you're using an older version of Typescript; if you update to TS >= 3.5, this problem should go away.